# @ModelAttribute in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, junit

I have a Spring Boot application (embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template...)
Here one of my controllers:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/company")
public class CompanyController {

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/list" }, method = { RequestMethod.GET })
    public String companyList(Company company, ModelMap model) {
        return serverContextPath + COMPANY_LIST_VIEW_NAME;
    }

    @ModelAttribute("companies")
    public Iterable<Company> companies(){
        return companyService.findAll();
    }
}
```

I've created this Junit Test to verify that my controller works fine

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { MyApplicationConfig.class })
public class CompanyControllerTests {


    private CompanyController controller;

    @Value("${server.contextPath}")
    protected String serverContextPath;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        controller = new CompanyController();
    }


    @Test
    public void testCompanyList() {

        ExtendedModelMap model = new ExtendedModelMap();
        String viewName = controller.companyList(new Company(), model);
        assertEquals(serverContextPath + CompanyController.COMPANY_LIST_VIEW_NAME, viewName);
        Iterable<Company> companies = (Iterable<Company>) model.get("companies");
        assertNotNull(companies);

    }    
}
```

But I have an AssertionError `assertNotNull(companies);`

Comment: And why should that be filled? You are directly calling a method, you aren't using the Spring MVC infrastructure for the testing.

Comment: MockMvc is what you need to test a controller.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to mock this call with some expected result:

```
companyService.findAll()
```

to be able to test controller apart from services